# Box2D Android Studio Drawing inverted shapes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, box2d

I'm creating a crash test game using Android Studio and LibGDX, I have everything I need on the game set, however I would like to create an upside down triangle like this in Box2D, Obviously, It's not going to look like this but this image is to give you an example[image: Example of my goal on Box2D]

However when I run it it looks like this:
[image: Actual result]

I've tried changing the order of the code in Box2D but it doesn't create an inverted triangle, like this :

```
private Fixture createcollisionFixture(Body collisionBody) {
        Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[3];
        vertices[0] = new Vector2(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        vertices[1] = new Vector2(0.5f, -0.5f);
        vertices[2] = new Vector2(0, 0.5f);
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.set(vertices);
        Fixture fix = collisionBodyBody.createFixture(shape, 1);
        shape.dispose();
        return fix;
    }
```

I change it to:

```
private Fixture createcollision2Fixture(Body collision2Body) {
        Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[3];
        vertices[2] = new Vector2(0, 0.5f);
        vertices[1] = new Vector2(0.5f, -0.5f);
        vertices[0] = new Vector2(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.set(vertices);
        Fixture fix = collision2Body.createFixture(shape, 1);
        shape.dispose();
        return fix;

    }
```

But it keeps loading as the second picture, not like an inverted triangle, how do I fix this? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in Box2D but in **coordinates that you are using to draw triangle**. No matter in what order you will be passing them to the Fixture they will produce triangle like this:

[image]

If you want to rotate the triangle you have to pass another set of coordinates like this:

[image]

So finally your code should look like:

```
    ...

    Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[3];
    vertices[2] = new Vector2(-0.5, 0.5f);
    vertices[1] = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    vertices[0] = new Vector2(0.5f, -0.5f);

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm!If my code looks like this, the triangle gets inverted!: vertices[2] = new Vector2(-0.5f, 0.5f);
        vertices[1] = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        vertices[0] = new Vector2(0, -0.5f);

Comment: Absolutely! Thumbs up!